# While starting apache with apachectl facing issue

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, apache-config, http-digest

When i am trying to start or stop apache with the command

```
/ebiz/apache/httpd/sbin/apachectl -k stop -f /ebiz/apache/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Getting this error:-

```
/ebiz/apache/httpd/sbin/apachectl: line 122: ./httpd: No such file or directory
```

But when i am trying to execute same command from sbin location it is working fine. I am placing my apache in custom location and my apachectl is in "/ebiz/apache/httpd/sbin" location and httpd.conf is in "/ebiz/apache/httpd/conf/" location

If i look my apachectl file

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
#
# Apache control script designed to allow an easy command line interface
# to controlling Apache.  Written by Marc Slemko, 1997/08/23
# 
# The exit codes returned are:
#   XXX this doc is no longer correct now that the interesting
#   XXX functions are handled by httpd
#   0 - operation completed successfully
#   1 - 
#   2 - usage error
#   3 - httpd could not be started
#   4 - httpd could not be stopped
#   5 - httpd could not be started during a restart
#   6 - httpd could not be restarted during a restart
#   7 - httpd could not be restarted during a graceful restart
#   8 - configuration syntax error
#
# When multiple arguments are given, only the error from the _last_
# one is reported.  Run "apachectl help" for usage info
#
ACMD="$1"
ARGV="$@"
#
# |||||||||||||||||||| START CONFIGURATION SECTION  ||||||||||||||||||||
# --------------------                              --------------------
# 
# the path to your httpd binary, including options if necessary
HTTPD='./httpd'
#
#
# a command that outputs a formatted text version of the HTML at the
# url given on the command line.  Designed for lynx, however other
# programs may work.  
if [ -x "/usr/bin/links" ]; then
  LYNX="/usr/bin/links -dump"
else
  LYNX=none
fi
#
# the URL to your server's mod_status status page.  If you do not
# have one, then status and fullstatus will not work.
STATUSURL="http://localhost:80/server-status"


#
# Set this variable to a command that increases the maximum
# number of file descriptors allowed per child process. This is
# critical for configurations that use many file descriptors,
# such as mass vhosting, or a multithreaded server.
ULIMIT_MAX_FILES="ulimit -S -n `ulimit -H -n`"
# --------------------                              --------------------
# ||||||||||||||||||||   END CONFIGURATION SECTION  ||||||||||||||||||||

# Set the maximum number of file descriptors allowed per child process.
if [ "x$ULIMIT_MAX_FILES" != "x" ] ; then
    $ULIMIT_MAX_FILES
fi

ERROR=0
if [ "x$ARGV" = "x" ] ; then 
    ARGV="-h"
fi

function checklynx() {
if [ "$LYNX" = "none" ]; then
   echo "The 'links' package is required for this functionality."
   exit 8
fi
}

function testconfig() {
# httpd is denied terminal access in SELinux, so run in the
# current context to get stdout from $HTTPD -t.
if test -x /usr/sbin/selinuxenabled && /usr/sbin/selinuxenabled; then
  runcon -- `id -Z` $HTTPD $OPTIONS -t
else
  $HTTPD $OPTIONS -t
fi
ERROR=$?
}

case $ACMD in
start|stop|restart|graceful|graceful-stop)
    $HTTPD $OPTIONS -k $ARGV
    ERROR=$?
    ;;
startssl|sslstart|start-SSL)
    echo The startssl option is no longer supported.
    echo Please edit httpd.conf to include the SSL configuration settings
    echo and then use "apachectl start".
    ERROR=2
    ;;
configtest)
    testconfig
    ;;
status)
    checklynx
    $LYNX $STATUSURL | awk ' /process$/ { print; exit } { print } '
    ;;
fullstatus)
    checklynx
    $LYNX $STATUSURL
    ;;
*)
    $HTTPD $OPTIONS "$@"
    ERROR=$?
esac

exit $ERROR
```

On the line number 122 it is looking for this "$HTTPD $OPTIONS "$@"". How i can execute apache from anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that the path to `httpd` is hardcoded to the relative path `./httpd` in `apachectl`:

```
# the path to your httpd binary, including options if necessary
HTTPD='./httpd'
```

which points to the wrong location if you're not in the right working directory.

It should be sufficient to change the path to the absolute path to the binary, i.e.

```
# the path to your httpd binary, including options if necessary
HTTPD=/ebiz/apache/httpd/sbin/httpd
```

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me to resolve my issue